# Does Auri have the Power of names?

Tags: patrick-rothfuss, the-slow-regard-of-silent-things

So some spoilers for Rothfuss new novella, the slow regard to silent things, towards the end we see that Auri

> is doing alchemy, but by her calculations it will take longer then she has, so she closes her eyes and finishes it in a flash. she also says she knows the secrets of things more so then even the masters of the university.

Later we see she even says that one day she'll give Kvothe a new name should he ever need it, in return for him giving her a name.

Throughout the entire book we see she learn the names of rooms, and objects as well, is she just crazy or does she legitimately know the names of all things/can learn them?

Answer (score 5):

Auri has some power, but what form it has is ill defined and warped by her broken mind.

Auri is broken. That is very much evident. She attributes thoughts and feelings to inanimate objects and places. She treats those feelings as more important than her own. She shows strong signs of an obsessive disorder, arranging all these objects to "fit together" in a way only she can perceive, that can change from day to day.  Her rationale behind this is linked to "how the world turns", as though she were in a great stopwatch and trying not to get crushed by the gears.

Naming power is linked to the true name, and true nature, of objects.  It's a very easy link to make, that Auri has somehow tapped into everything on a large scale. There are many broken people in Haven that show it's possible.  The saddest part of Auri, in my opinion, is that its also possible that she's not, that something mundane broke her will, that she has no better understanding of Names or the ruins she hides in than anything else.

Her great tragedy is that we the readers know its possible, in her world, that a bronze gear can be obstinate. I'd want her to be right about that, that all she suffers means something. But for her to spend a week mulling it over where it goes, along with every other piece she finds down there... she may be in tune with something, but she is also broken.

In fact, since she's usually very afraid of changing something too far out of its nature, I'd say she's not using Naming. Knowing a Name involves understanding a thing, which she may / may not have an innate ability on, but calling the Name, invoking it, is to bend it to your will, which Auri is loathe to do in the simplest of situations. She cant even salvage bed linens without something else balancing her internal scales.

Rothfuss has mentioned there are other powers, other magics. I'd almost believe she'd tapped into something worthy of Fae, but there's little to say either way.

Comment: thats why i think she isnt broken at all, that she literally understands what using a name means and does, and because of that she chooses to live in seclusion. righting her own world, since the world above is so misused that those objects call out to her to be fixed and its to much.

Comment: @Himarm - noted, and added a few thoughts to my answer, but I rather think that she was greatly misused rather than the world around her, so likely we'll just disagree. In a book thats wholly about one unique perspective,  there should be some room for that.

Comment: plus we still have so much to wait for that will shed light, hopfully he wont pull a GRRM and take to much longer on book 3 haha.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. It's not clear to me that Auri has something like OCD, rather I was thinking that she (like Kvothe and other of Rothfuss' characters) has survived great trauma (hinted at by the way she references being some other person before) and the ordering behaviors are a way for her to avoid thoughts and outward actions/environments that would be triggering.

Comment: @Lexible - Yeah, I Am Not A Psychologist, and I agree she survived something that some of her thoughts skirt around, "obsessive" was just the closest label to fit her, until/if better understanding arrives.

Comment: @Radhil I tend to think of many/most psychiatric diagnostic categories as soft but *useful ontological lenses*, rather than very hard categories (like, uh, 'infected with *plasmodium falparcicum*'). So OCD completely reasonable... its genesis possibly quite interesting. I just hope we get to learn much more about her in TDoS.

Answer (score 2):

I was pondering the exact same thing...I'm starting to believe that Auri is much more wise (and powerful) than we've initially been led to think. That said she also appears to have no interest whatsoever in using these abilities for herself (she actually seems very opposed to the idea). I loved this little story but I just want to know more now! I sincerely hope we get more answers in TDOS...

Comment: it hints at something dramatic in the story too, and she says how empty and sad she was before kvothe gave her a name, i had already been thinking that kvothe gives up his name and takes a new name, but after reading this, im now possitive, i think auri must have lost her name, which is why she has been hiding down their, but by being given a new name, she has started to basically become a person again  i cant wait for the next book either. !

Answer (score 2):

I see two times at the farm house while scavenging that she used nameing. When she sees the dog, the description of the dog shows its a guard dog. It growls slightly at her then she pets it and just goes to sleep. No guard dog would do that. And again when the child in the window sees her. I believe she calls the name of the wind because all of a sudden her hair covers her face. The description made it sound as if it was just floating around in  constant movement. Auri is something very special and almost believe she is the one kvothe is truly in love with.

Comment: Welcome to the site! This looks like a good start. I recommend you take our [tour] to find out what sort of answers we like to see. Specifically, I recommend you add a couple of sources or quotes to back up what you are saying, and your interpretation of the events. Good luck!

Comment: Agreed. Sources would make this a much better answer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Auri knows the Name of things. Not all things, like Taborlin, but things,like solid objects. You need to read The Slow Regard of Silent Things to really get a grasp of this, though. On a side note, 'Kote' means disaster. Gives a bit of a hint as to why Kvothe changed his name, doesn't it? I think Auri, at one point, tried to fix the whole world,and it overwhelmed her. She was 'full of screaming', and the masters put her in the Rookery. Now she fixes the Underthing, 'her corner of the world'. She is so much more powerful and mysterious than we'll ever likely learn, however. It doesn't seem like we'll get Auri's full story in Doors of Stone, but I hope we get more hints so we can develop better theories. What I'd really like is a collection of books like Slow Regard of Silent Things. I don't want to pin down Auri's past. She, like Denna, is not one to be pinned down with words. I just want to get a better look into Auri's hidden world. I want to learn about the perfect shadows of the Underthing. Damn, now I sound like Auri herself

Comment: When you answer a question please ensure it is full of facts and you have sources to back it. In stackexchange speculations and assumptions are not promoted.